# WSL2 автозапуск nginx, php, mariadb

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, wsl, wsl2

При запуске "wsl2" как сделать так чтобы не приходилось запускать вручную (nginx, php8.1-fpm, mariadb)

WSL2
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Пробовал

```
sudo update-rc.d nginx defaults
sudo systemctl enable nginx
```

но после перезапуска WSL2, nginx не запускается

можно ли как нибудь запускать через ".bashrc"

Answer (score 0):

На Виндовс 11 в файле `/etc/wsl.conf` пропиши

```
[boot]
command="systemctl start nginx"
```

Через ".bashrc" для Windows 10 если не сработает первый способ

```
wsl.exe -u root systemctl start nginx || wsl.exe -u root systemctl start nginx
```

https://askubuntu.com/a/1356147/179720

Comment: Чуток поменял код и получилось спасибо!